Nuxt 3 / Vue 3: Reactive Value Initialization Delay Causing Zero Value
Problem Description
I'm working with a reactive data flow where a calculated value (final percentage) is not immediately populating with the correct value due to data loading delays.
Specific Scenario

I have computed/reactive values totalScore and totalMaxScore
When initially accessing finalPercentage, it returns 0
A watcher on the same values shows the correct calculated value
The zero value is being used in other parts of the application before the actual value is loaded

Am just trying to get finalPercentage correct value instead of zero, so i can use the value to get a badge level.
Right now, only on the template its displaying the value correctly
Code Example
const { data: scoreData } = useFindManyAttempt({
    where: {
      clientTrackId: +clientTrackId,
      playerId: user?.id,
    },
    include: {
      answers: true,
    },
  });

  // Calculate total score and max score
  const totalScore = computed(() => {
    return (
      scoreData.value?.reduce((acc, attempt) => {
        return (
          acc + attempt.answers.reduce((sum, answer) => sum + answer.score, 0)
        );
      }, 0) || 0
    );
  });

  const totalMaxScore = computed(() => {
    return (
      scoreData.value?.reduce((acc, attempt) => {
        return (
          acc +
          attempt.answers.reduce((sum, answer) => sum + answer.maxScore, 0)
        );
      }, 0) || 0
    );
  });

  // Calculate final percentage
  const finalPercentage = computed(() => {
    return totalMaxScore.value > 0
      ? Math.round((totalScore.value / totalMaxScore.value) * 100)
      : "0";
  });

// Watcher shows correct value, but initial access shows 0
watch([totalScore, totalMaxScore], () => {
  console.log('Actual calculated percentage:', finalPercentage.value)
})

 console.log("finalPercentage", finalPercentage.value) // getting 0

return {
    finalPercentage,
  };


Can you clarify what is the problem? If the component can't work correctly until data is loaded then don't render it until it's loaded

I wanted to pass the finalPercentage correct value inside defineOgImageComponent instead of zero or undefined since it was taking time to load. @EstusFlask

There's no defineOgImageComponent  in your code. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for the problem including useFindManyAttempt implementation and explain how it's intended to work, so an appropriate answer could be given. Currently it looks like you need to await for a promise somewhere instead of using reactive useFind... composable
